# Adding texture file to QGIS 3D view?

Tags: qgis, 3d

I am trying to visualize a 3D .img file in QGIS 3.6 . I can add the .img file, as well as a .tiff overlay to my map. When I create a new 3D view, I am able to select the .img as the elevation (which appears to work fine), but the view outputs a large, single color (green or gray depending on my overlay) blob with no defined texture. Does anybody have a fix for this? Adjusting the 3D view resolution options does not work as a fix. I have inserted relevant images:

[image: settings]

[image: output sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up...

I supposed my laptop does not have the hardware requirements to render the 3D scene properly. After transferring the project to a more powerful PC, the 3D view appeared properly.